Switch network interface back to auto/dynamic IP address using C/C++ Linux
There are tons of examples in the Internet about how to set a Static IP address to a network interface under Linux using C language.
One of the most popular is How to set the IP address from C in linux
I have a task to switch a local network interface back to dyamic IP allocation from DHCP server progframmatically using C language under Linux. But could not find anything in the Internet.
Is there any way to achieve this using similar "smart" programming way as most prorammers do for setting Static IP, I mean by calling ioctl() function, or some other kernel functions?

C and C++ are different languages.  Please use the correct one in your titles, text, and tags and remove the one you're not using.  "I have a task to switch a local network interface back to dyamic IP allocation" Are you trying to implement the DHCP client process yourself, or just configure the system to do it with the standard networking stack?

Take a look at the source code of a shell utility that does this to see what calls it makes.

Since these utilities are almost invariably written in C, and they can do it, obviously it can be done similarly by you.

"There are tons of examples in the Internet about how to set a Static IP address to a network interface under Linux using C language." -- not exactly.  There are examples of setting an IP address, but whether that is considered a static or dynamic one is a function of how you choose the address, not of what address you set or how you tell the interface to use it.  The interface and its driver do not know.

If your Linux distribution is using systemd (in particular systemd-networkd) to manage its networking behavior, you could do this by writing out the new settings for the network device (including DHCP=yes in the [Network] section) to an ASCII/INI file like /run/systemd/network/10_mydevicename.network and then executing /bin/networkctrl reload to get systemd-networkd to rescan the config files and apply the new settings.

If I understand right, even changes with ioctl() are applied until the next restart of a system. Also, if the IP is set over ioctl(), IT IS Static, as it is set by user and not by DHCP. Even if it is the same as it was before set, after the call ioctl() it becomes Static. What happens with the IP after restart is defined by a config file, located whatever the   linux distro defines (f.e. /etc/network/interfaces under Ubuntu). And turn back to DHCP is only possible when 1) IP is defined as auto/dhcp in .../interfaces, 2) when ifdown/ifup is called to force the service to re-read ../interfaces

Also have to consider, that some linux distros have kind of NetworkManagers, that control the network interfaces on top, and they have their own config files. So every time when you want to change network settings permanent, you have to decide if you use NetworkManager (or modify its config files, in most cases in YAML format), or you disable those UI services and modify files like /etc/network/interfaces manally or programmatically.


Switch network interface back to auto/dynamic IP address using C/C++ Linux

You can't "switch" interface back to a dynamic IP. The interface is "static" - in the sense, it is inanimate. It doesn't "do" anything, an interface sends and receives packets.
A service, a program can receive and send packets using this interface, and using a protocol like DHCP or using an algorithm , like one described in rfc4941 , that program can take action and actually assign an ip address to the interface.
The actual configuration, of such service (if any) is used on your system, is very, very specific to the system you are using and the specific your configuration you are using. There are a plethora of different DHCP clients available on Linux, and you may also write your own, and there are also more network "configurators" programs for system administrators. To mention some of the programs: dhcpcd, systemd-networkd, NetworkManager, dhclient, netctl . Your system may or may not use any or none or multiple of them.

I mean by calling ioctl() function, or some other kernel functions?

No. In other words, the kernel itself does not cotain a DHCP client.

After studying information about the topic, I can summarize it in the following way.

Dynamic IP address can be configured in the network configuration file, which , if we speack about debian/ubuntu, is /etc/network/interfaces
Some UI Linux distributives like Ubuntu have special services like NetworkManager, that manage the network interfaces based on their own configuration files, and igonre network interfaces only if they listed in system config files like /etc/network/configuration. By default this file is absent in the ubuntu.
If you want to manipulate network interfaces programmatically by system calls like ioctl(), you have to disable such NetworkManagers by stopping that services, or even disable them. But...
Manipulation over ioctl() gives temporarily effect until next reboot, after that the system applies again the settings from /etc/network/interfaces
That means, if you want to change the network config permanently, you have to either maniuplate NetworkManager config files, of if you stopped them - manipulate /etc/network/interfaces
The latter one is not so easy to change, as the file does not have format of INI. Example is here. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/setting-up-an-network-interfaces-file/
So you have to be ready to parse it in some specific manner, change some lines and write back. Or overwrite it completely every time.

What about the DHCP as it stays in the topic. The only way to turn back to DHCP is to change config file (or enshure the interface is alrady configured there as dhcp) and restart the interface. In some cases it may require phisical unplug/plug the cable from the Ethernet slot, because DHCP server re-allocate IP for your network interface only when it physically reconnected. Or device Rebooted.
